# IP masking HTML input form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masking

So I need to validate an input field to accept IP addresses.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type='text' placeholder='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' name='IP'>
</form>
```

Since there is no IP value for the attribute `type`, I would need to validate it using **Javascript** or some client-sided language. I've reached to this **jQuery** snippet using a [mask library](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js).

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("input").mask("9?99.9?99.9?99.9?99", {placeholder:" "});
});
```

This however doesn't work on my side. Here is how I include the scripts *(just to point out)*.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, even if I manage to make this work, it still isn't the best option since two-digit parts of an IP address won't be rendered properly *(i.e. 84.55.11.499)*. So my questions are:

1. Why does the above code not work on my end but does on **JSFiddle**?
2. How do I filter two-digit IP addresses with the **mask library**?

Answer (score 14):

I know is late, I know you need jQuery, but just in case you didn't knew it in HTML5 you can use pattern attribute with a regular expresion...

For example:

```
<input required pattern="^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$">
```

That regular expresion will validate IP addresses like:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
x.x.x.x
xx.xx.xx.xx
x.xx.xxx.xx
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you're already using a jQuery plugin - try this one that has a fully working IP mask

[This plugin here](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

it's done like this:

```
 $('.ip_address').mask('0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ', {translation: {'Z': {pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true}}});
```

or the identical - little shorter:

```
 $('.ip_address').mask('099.099.099.099');
```

the last example is the last line used in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54hh2/2) example

according to the jQuery mask docs :

0: Only Numbers.

9: Only Numbers but optional.

so you see - `099.099.099.099`, if you wanted to force 2 digits in between each decimal `009.009.009.009`

Comment: Doesn't really answer my questions.

Comment: yes it does, if you chose to use this plugin - you would use the line of code I showed.  THis is how to mask with the decimal points - each section at least one number , but allows for 3 numbers .  These are the rules for IP address text box

Comment: see it work here -   I pasted the minified mask javascript in there , it was easier then uploading....  http://jsfiddle.net/54hh2/2/

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't count 2-digit numbers as part of an IP address.

Comment: yes it does , hit space bar or "." after the 2 digits

Comment: That code is dependent on jQuery and jQUeryUI, you have both of those loaded , right?

Comment: @Scott Selby i want to validate the field when the filed if the user enter 192.3.4. and forgot to put value after . then i want to validate the user how can i do that

Comment: @UsamaLucky - that is a seperate question , google jquery validate ip address

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, But I think the following code is the correct answer.

For Example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-input" id="ipv4" name="ipv4" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"/>
```

Jquery code

```
var ipv4_address = $('#ipv4');
ipv4_address.inputmask({
   alias: "ip",
   "placeholder": "_"
});
```

[This code in codepen](https://codepen.io/hoshmand1/pen/yxrNGp?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me finely.

download this js file from :
[https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js]
or
[https://github.com/shahram4m/blogfy/blob/main/static/js/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js]
and reference it to your page.
then using this Jquery code :

```
var ipv4_address = $('#ipInput');
ipv4_address.inputmask({
   alias: "ip",
   "placeholder": "_"
});
```